# UISlider is not working in particular language in ios

Tags: objective-c, swift, uislider

I'm using `UISlider` in my app. App localization is there. If the app's language is English `UISlider` works fine but with other language can't able to increase or decrease value using slider.

Comment: Your code is in Objective C or Swift ?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: My code is in objective c

Comment: @Sivagami yes, but what is it?

Comment: Hey something went wrong in increementing the value thats why it's not working... I'm getting the maxValue from server. If I hard code the value its working... 
  [slider setMaximumValue:[valueFromServer floatValue]];
valueFromServer becomes 0 only when we run the app in one particular language. It retrieves the value for all other languages like English etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UISlider doesn't have any problem with localisation.

Your code for changing value must be like this and your method mush value `valueChanged` action.

**Kindly refer below code.**

```
- (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender
{  
    myTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", [sender value]];  
}
```